# I'm having trouble having the body parts of the snake follow the head's path

Tags: java, computer-science, game-development

Board.Java (Logic part of the program)

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable{
private final int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500,TWIDTH = WIDTH/25, THEIGHT = HEIGHT/25, RAND_POS = 29;
private int foodLocX, foodLocY, snakeHeadX = 240, snakeHeadY = 240;;
private boolean running = true, up = false,down = false,left = false,right = true;
private JFrame frame;
private Thread t;
private ArrayList<BodyPart> body;
public Board() {
    frame = new JFrame("Snake");
    initBoard();
    foodLocX = snakeHeadX + 8*TWIDTH;
    foodLocY = snakeHeadY;
    body = new ArrayList<BodyPart>();
    body.add(new BodyPart(snakeHeadX,snakeHeadY, TWIDTH));
    t = new Thread(this);
}

public void initBoard() {
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(518,540));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    frame.addKeyListener(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void locateApple() {

    int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
    foodLocX = ((r * TWIDTH));

    r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
    foodLocY = ((r * THEIGHT));

    while(foodLocX >= WIDTH || foodLocY >= HEIGHT || foodLocX < 0 || foodLocY < 0) {
         r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
         foodLocX = ((r * TWIDTH));

         r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
         foodLocY = ((r * THEIGHT));
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    for(int i = 0; i<WIDTH;i+=TWIDTH) {
        for(int ii = 0; ii<HEIGHT;ii+=THEIGHT) {
            g.fillRect(i, ii, TWIDTH, THEIGHT);
        }
    }

    if(foodLocX == body.get(0).getX() && foodLocY == body.get(0).getY()) {
        int x = body.get(body.size()-1).getX();
        int y = body.get(body.size()-1).getY();

        if(right) {
            body.add(new BodyPart(x+20,y,TWIDTH));
        }if(left) {
            body.add(new BodyPart(x-20,y,TWIDTH));
        }if(down) {
            body.add(new BodyPart(x,y+20,TWIDTH));
        }if(up) {
            body.add(new BodyPart(x,y-20,TWIDTH));
        }
        locateApple();
    }
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(foodLocX, foodLocY, TWIDTH, THEIGHT);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(int i = 0; i< body.size();i++) {
        body.get(i).draw(g);
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !down) {
        up = true;
        down = false;
        left = false;
        right = false;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(55,666);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !up) {
        up = false;
        down = true;
        left = false;
        right = false;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(55,666);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !left) {
        up = false;
        down = false;
        left = false;
        right = true;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(55,666);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !right) {
        up = false;
        down = false;
        left = true;
        right = false;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100,666);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0){};
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0){}

//public void addBodyPart() {
    //body.add(previousHead); // Part that I left off on
//}

public void moveSnake() {
    if(right) {
        for(int i = 0; i<body.size();i++) {
            body.get(i).setX(body.get(i).getX()+20);
        }
    }if(left) {
        for(int i = 0; i<body.size();i++) {
            body.get(i).setX(body.get(i).getX()-20);
        }
    }if(down) {
        for(int i = 0; i<body.size();i++) {
            body.get(i).setY(body.get(i).getY()+20);
        }
    }if(up) {
        for(int i = 0; i<body.size();i++) {
            body.get(i).setY(body.get(i).getY()-20);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void run() {
    while(running) {

        if(body.get(0).getX()<0 || body.get(0).getX()>480 || body.get(0).getY()<0 || body.get(0).getY()>480){
            System.out.println("Game Over!\nYour snake was " + body.size() + " blocks long");
            endGame();
        }

        moveSnake();

        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(75,666);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void startGame() {
    t.start();
}

public void endGame() {
    t.stop();
}
}
```

Main.java (Runnable program)

```
package snake;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b = new Board();
        b.startGame();
    }

}
```

BodyPart.java

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class BodyPart {

    private int x,y,tilesize;
    public BodyPart(int x, int y, int tilesize) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.tilesize = tilesize;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x,y,tilesize,tilesize);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

This troubles me because it adds a body part to the array list, however the parts do not follow the body once I make a move. I'm lost and not sure what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all so much.

-AbysssCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the `moveSnake()` method you are iterating over the body and moving each part of the body the same amount (you're picking up the entire snake and moving it, not having it "slither").

Instead of moving the entire snake - you need the arrow keys to move just the "head", or the "parent". You then need to code the rest the snake as "children", where each new part of the snake sets its new location to the current location of its parent.

For example, if your snake is only 2 units long, the arrow keys will determine the position of the first unit, the "head" only. Then `for each bodypart : yoursnake` (psuedocode) you would set the new location to `bodyPart.getParentBodyPart.getLocation()`  or something of similar logic.

This is ugly since I just threw it together with what you had - you can definitely clean it up. But it will work:

```
public void moveSnake() {
    if(right) {
        // iterate from the tail forward so we don't overwrite positions that we need
        for(int i = body.size()-1; i>=0;i--) {
            if (i == 0) {
                body.get(i).setX(body.get(i).getX()+20);
            } else {
                // we dont know what direct we are moving, so we need x and y
                body.get(i).setX(body.get(i-1).getX());
                body.get(i).setY(body.get(i-1).getY());
            }

        }
    }if(left) {
        for(int i = body.size()-1; i>=0;i--) {
            if (i == 0) {
                body.get(i).setX(body.get(i).getX()-20);
            } else {
                body.get(i).setX(body.get(i-1).getX());
                body.get(i).setY(body.get(i-1).getY());
            }

        }
    }if(down) {
        for(int i = body.size()-1; i>=0;i--) {
            if (i == 0) {
                body.get(i).setY(body.get(i).getY()+20);
            } else {
                body.get(i).setY(body.get(i-1).getY());
                body.get(i).setX(body.get(i-1).getX());
            }

        }
    }if(up) {
        for(int i = body.size()-1; i>=0;i--) {
            if (i == 0) {
                body.get(i).setY(body.get(i).getY()-20);
            } else {
                body.get(i).setY(body.get(i-1).getY());
                body.get(i).setX(body.get(i-1).getX());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help - I must confess I played snake longer than I'd care to admit after getting it to work :~p